# How to test react component with jest?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I want to test the Sidebar component. When you click on the "ToggleButton" it should toggle sidebar by className, but when clicking, an error appears stating that the function was not found...

Thank you!

Error: `TypeError: setToggleSidebar is not a function`

##### `Sidebar.test.tsx`

```tsx
describe("Sidebar", () => {
  test("Toggle Sidebar", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useToggleSidebar());

    const { toggleSidebar } = result.current;

    ComponentRender(<ToggleButton toggleFunc={toggleSidebar} />);
    ComponentRender(<Sidebar />);

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("toggle-button"));

    expect(screen.getByTestId("sidebar")).toHaveClass("HiddenSidebar");
  });
});
```

##### `componentRender.tsx`

```tsx
export function ComponentRender(component: JSX.Element, options: IComponentRenderOptions = {}) {
  const { route = "/dashboard", initialState } = options;

  return render(
    <ReduxProvider initialState={initialState}>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <SidebarProvider>
          <MemoryRouter initialEntries={[route]}>{component}</MemoryRouter>
        </SidebarProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ReduxProvider>,
  );
}
```

##### `sidebarProvider.tsx`

```tsx
export const SidebarProvider = (props: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const { children } = props;

  const [isSidebarShow, setToggleSidebar] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const defaultValue: ISidebarDefault = useMemo(
    () => ({
      isSidebarShow,
      setToggleSidebar,
    }),
    [isSidebarShow],
  );

  return <SidebarContext.Provider value={defaultValue}>{children}</SidebarContext.Provider>;
};
```

##### `useToggleSidebar.tsx`

```tsx
const useToggleSidebar = (): IUseToggleSidebar => {
  const { isSidebarShow, setToggleSidebar } = useContext(SidebarContext);

  const toggleSidebar = () => {
    setToggleSidebar((isSidebarShow: boolean) => !isSidebarShow);

    ^ <-- HERE IS ERROR setToggleSidebar is not a function

  };

  return { isSidebarShow, toggleSidebar };
};
```

I tried to destructure the useToggleSidebar hook directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap your hook inside Context

```
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useToggleSidebar(), {
      wrapper: SidebarProvider
    });
```

Beause you were rendering `useToggleSidebar` lack of context, just simulator it like the real one